# Normalize company names using a long set of rules

Tags: parsing, text-mining, data-cleaning

We have a large table (>30M rows) containing company names and other characteristics.

Data:

```
Company_id  Type Name               Adress  (more...)
497651684   8    Big mall Toys'rUs  BigMall adress   
468468486   1    McDonnnals         WhateverStreet
161684314   8    Toys R Us          Another street
546846846   1    BgKing             BigMall2 adress
484984988   5    IKEA store103      Other Mall
489616848   5    Mss Duty           Addrs
484984984   5    Pull&Bear          Adrss
468484867   5    Zara store         Adress2
(...)
```

From that table, we have identified about ~300 company groups whose name could be normalized easily with something on lines of:

```
if type is (8,10,85,2)
and
(
contains name ("toys","us")
or
stringDistance name("toys R us") < (X)
)
new name is "Toys 'R us"


if type is (1,90,7)
and
(contains name("donalds")
or
stringDistance name("mcdonalds") < (X)
)
new name is "Mc donalds"

(...)
```

I'm not sure what would be the best approach for this honestly. We previously did an ad-hoc approach for a way smaller set with a simpler logic for a fast solution. But this time I would love to know what would be the ideal way.

Answer (score 0):

While String edit distance e.g. stringDistance name("toys R us") < (X) is a good approach, I will also recommend trying to use clustering especially hierarchical clustering here.

All the names falling into the same cluster should have the same standard company name. For the above to work you will have to cut the dendogram (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrogram) of the hierarchy pretty close to the leaves. You will have to try different features (the ones used in calculating the distance or similarity) of your clustering to arrive at a suitable set. Examples can be representing each company name as a vector of characters and then using cosine similarity to measure distances. Btw, cosine similarity works great for texts.

Comment: Indeed a previous clustering phase should be done. My biggest problem currently is how to apply a big amount of rules in an efficient way.

Comment: If you are doing clustering, you dont need to apply any "rules". That is the whole idea behind AI that it discovers the rules autmatically based on the features you provide. Hence just choose the features, and do clustering. That should give you something worthwhile if you have given the right set of features.